# How to read binary file in distributed manner using Erlang?

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang, binary-data

I have few binary files of moderate size (1 to 5 GB) which I want to read and process using Erlang.

Each file has records of varying sizes, i.e. one record will be 200 kb but other record may be 800 kb size. Record size can be obtained by reading first few bytes of record. As it is a binary file, there's no delimiter between two records.

To process these files we can write multithreaded program but just for having fun I thought of processing files in parallel using Erlang.

I am newbie to Erlang so I don't know how I can split files into chunks and pass these chunks to Erlang processes.

Can anyone please give some ideas?

Comment: Generally I would go about this by having one "reader" process which reads records and then dispatches them to one or more worker processes. This limits the amount of extra work the reading process has to do (thus ensuring it's reading as fast as possible) by shifting the heavy lifting (your post-read processing) to different processes/cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this many times in other programming languages, and it was a fun learning exercise in Erlang.

The basic strategy is that you tell each process its starting byte offset, record size, and number of records to read. (If you have different-sized records in one file, you might pass a list of record sizes, like `[200, 800, 800, 800, 800, 200, 100]`). The workers process their chunk independently and return the result to the parent.

I think it's easy enough that you can figure it out yourself. You'll want to look at `erlang:spawn`, `file:open`, `file:read`, and `file:position` as the main pieces. But if you want the spoilers, here's my implementation of a module that reads numbers from a binary file and finds the average using multiple processes.  (I'm not an Erlang expert, so there may be better ways of doing this.)

```
-module(average).

-export([write_file/3, read_file/4]).
-export([read_file_worker/5]).

write_file(Filename, BlockSize, ListOfNumbers) ->
    BS = BlockSize*8,
    BinData = [<<X:BS>> || X <- ListOfNumbers],
    {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(Filename, [write, raw, binary]),
    file:write(IoDevice, BinData),
    file:close(IoDevice).

read_file(Filename, BlocksPerProcess, BlockSize, TotalBlockCount) ->
    {ok, SpawnCount} = read_file_spawner(Filename, BlocksPerProcess, BlockSize, TotalBlockCount, 0, 0),
    {ok, Sum} = read_file_listener(SpawnCount, 0),
    io:format("Total sum: ~p~nNumbers seen: ~p~nAverage: ~p~n", [Sum, TotalBlockCount, Sum/TotalBlockCount]).

read_file_spawner(Filename, BlocksPerProcess, BlockSize, TotalBlockCount, BlockOffset, SpawnCount) when BlockOffset < TotalBlockCount ->
    Offset = BlockOffset * BlockSize,
    MaxBlocks = min(BlocksPerProcess, TotalBlockCount - BlockOffset),
    spawn(?MODULE, read_file_worker, [self(), Filename, Offset, BlockSize, MaxBlocks]),
    read_file_spawner(Filename, BlocksPerProcess, BlockSize, TotalBlockCount, BlockOffset + BlocksPerProcess, SpawnCount + 1);
read_file_spawner(_Filename, _BlocksPerProcess, _BlockSize, _TotalBlockCount, _BlockOffset, SpawnCount) ->
    {ok, SpawnCount}.

read_file_listener(0, Accum) ->
    {ok, Accum};
read_file_listener(SpawnCount, Accum) ->
    receive
    {ok, Number} ->
        io:format("Got ~p~n", [Number]),
        read_file_listener(SpawnCount - 1, Accum + Number)
    end.

read_file_worker(MasterPid, Filename, Offset, BlockSize, MaxBlocks) ->
    {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(Filename, [read, raw, binary]),
    {ok, Offset} = file:position(IoDevice, {bof, Offset}),
    {ok, Sum} = read_file_worker_loop(IoDevice, BlockSize, 0, MaxBlocks, 0),
    MasterPid ! {ok, Sum}.

read_file_worker_loop(IoDevice, BlockSize, BlocksRead, MaxBlocks, Accum) when BlocksRead < MaxBlocks ->
    {ok, BinData} = file:read(IoDevice, BlockSize),
    Number = binary:decode_unsigned(BinData),
    read_file_worker_loop(IoDevice, BlockSize, BlocksRead + 1, MaxBlocks, Accum + Number);
read_file_worker_loop(_IoDevice, _BlockSize, _BlocksRead, _MaxBlocks, Accum)  ->
    {ok, Accum}.
```

And here it is in action, reading 10 numbers from a file using 5 processes:

```
12> Numbers = [1,1,2,4,6,10,10,1,0,500].                                  
[1,1,2,4,6,10,10,1,0,500]
13> average:write_file("/tmp/test.binary", 32, Numbers).                  
ok
14> average:read_file("/tmp/file.binary", 2, 32, length(Numbers)).        
Got 500
Got 11
Got 6
Got 16
Got 2
Total sum: 535
Numbers seen: 10
Average: 53.5
ok
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was on Christmas holiday. Many thanks for sharing your knowledge. I am trying your program on my machine, will let you know my results soon.

Answer (score 0):

Why not launching a process for each file? I can't see the value of splitting small files into chunks. Your files are already small. This can be parallelized on many machines also.